# Why can I not change user interface language?

Tags: windows-10, language-pack

I'm trying to change user interface language from polish to english on a Windows 10 computer. However, I keep getting spammed with errors when I attempt to change the language.

I'm logged in with an administrator account on the computer. The Windows Event Viewer does not give any hints about the root of this error.

The error comes when attempt to edit languages in **Time & Language** > **Region & Language** I message I get is :

[image]

I do not speak polish myself, but Google Translate says this means :

> Windows can not access the specified device, path, or file. You can
>   not have the appropriate permission to access the item.

What does this error mean, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Are you using Windows 10 Single Language Home, Windows 10 Home, or Windows 10 Professional? If you can't speak polish why do you have a polish language pack installed?

Comment: @Ramhound It is a Windows 10 Professional. The computer was bought by our polish office, but must be changed to english in order for our support to be able to provide any support...

Comment: You are logged in a Domain Administrator if connected to a domain and/or logged in as a local Administrator if not connected to a domain?

Comment: This seems like permission issue or the file may be corrupt. Once again check you have administrative privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to permissions. The post https://serverfault.com/questions/731511/windows-10-ad-domain-admin-with-missing-rights outlines the steps required to fix this issue (the title was somewhat misleading). The answer provided by HEDMON to that post solved this issue :

> 1. Win + R and type 'secpol.msc' for open the Local Security Policy console.
> 2. In the Security Settings tree, open Local Policies > Security Options.
> 3. Find the policy: User Account Control: Admin Approval Mode for the Built-in Administrator account and enable it.
> 4. Log out - log in, voilá!

Comment: You should submit a complete answer.  Link-only answers even to serverfault are not that help, the linked question in theory could be deleted, if that were to happen your answer would be just a link.,

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.